# How to read QWeb variable in javascript in Odoo 10?

Tags: javascript, odoo, qweb

i want to use qweb variables in script.

```
    <t t-set="test_var" t-value="TEST_VAR_VALUE"/>              

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var result = <t t-esc="test_var"/>;
document.getElementById("div_id").innerHTML = result;
</script>
```

i tried above code but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to give a `t-set` option for this.You can simply use a `span`  for this.

```
 <span class="test_class" t-att-data-test_var="TEST_VAR_VALUE"/>
    <script>
        $( function() {
            var result = $( ".test_class" ).data().test_var;
            });
    </script>
```